# Display multiple chart in the same page

Tags: highcharts, symfony-3.2

I'im using symfony 3.2 and ObHighchartsBundle , I'd like to know how to display many charts in the same page.
Right now I'm able to display only one chart called "statMontant".
I'd like to display the second chart inside the div with id "linechart2"

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
        <div id="linechart" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
  </div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
        <div id="linechart2" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/4.1.8/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/4.1.8/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    {{ chart(statMontant ) }}
    {{ chart(statEva) }}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you show the php code where do you initialize Highcharts?

Comment: it is done thnx     
        $graph1 = $this->statMontant($request);
        $graph1->chart->renderTo('graph1');
        $graph2 = $this->EVA($request);
        $graph2->chart->renderTo('graph2');
        $graph3 = $this->Bar($request);
        $graph3->chart->renderTo('graph3');
        return $this->render(':projet:statprojet.html.twig', array(

                'graph1' => $graph1,
                'graph2' => $graph2,
                'graph3' => $graph3,
                'projets' => $projets
            )
        );
    } in controller

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        {{ chart(graph1) }}
        {{ chart(graph2) }}
        {{ chart(graph3) }}
    </script>

Comment: Check this thread on `ObHighchartsBundle` github: https://github.com/marcaube/ObHighchartsBundle/issues/7

Comment: thank you @Wojciech Chmiel  it is work